# Inserting the values from another table while creating new table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my [***FIDDLE***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6aaed/4).

I am trying to import the data from old table to new table.  In old table there are many no of repetitions.  In new table i am able to insert only DISTINCT emails.  I am unable to Insert the name as same.  Here is my code.

```
CREATE TABLE table_old(name VARCHAR(255), email VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO table_old (name, email) VALUES ('tom', 'tom@gmail.com'),
                                           ('peter', 'peter@gmail.com'),
                                           ('hitler', 'hitler@gmail.com'),
                                           ('haasan', 'haasan@gmail.com'),
                                           ('arun', 'arun@gmail.com'),
                                           ('tom', 'tom@gmail.com'),
                                           ('peter', 'peter@gmail.com'),
                                           ('hitler', 'hitler@gmail.com'),
                                           ('haasan', 'haasan@gmail.com'),
                                           ('arun', 'arun@gmail.com');

CREATE TABLE table_new AS (SELECT DISTINCT email FROM table_old );
```

So please give me idea how to insert the names into table_new with respect to the email column name.

Comment: Just add the name?  `CREATE TABLE table_new AS (SELECT DISTINCT name, email FROM table_old );`

Comment: I interpret this as wanting only one copy of each even if the names are different.

Comment: Yes Joe.  You are right.  I need only a copy of the redundant content. And tim is faster to solve my problem though you are right.

Comment: First i created the table with user_id with auto inc and primary key. Later i am trying the above query with alter table command. I am getting error. cant i do that.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
CREATE TABLE table_new AS (SELECT name, email FROM table_old GROUP BY name, email);
```

Comment: First i created the table with user_id with auto inc and primary key.  Later i am trying the above query with alter table command.  I am getting error. cant i do that.?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below query.

`CREATE TABLE table_new AS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table_old );`

Answer (score 1):

Some of this depends on how you want to select the name that is kept.  It could be as easy as:

```
CREATE TABLE table_new AS (SELECT email, max(name) FROM table_old group by email);
```

If you have more complex rules for determining which name is chosen, that would need to be implemented differently.